# Does the following protocol of secure a matrix satisfy one-time-pad?

Tags: provable-security, randomness, one-time-pad

**Problem Definition:**
Alice wants to send a matrix $MR_A$ which encrypts its original private matrix $M_A$ ($M\times N$ size, all elements in $M_A$ is in {0,1,2,3,4,5}) to Bob without letting Bob knows any information about $M_A$.
**Security Definition:**
Alice and Bob communicate via a secure channel(no need to consider the other attacker, and no need to consider secrete recovery since this protocol is just one of the steps of another protocol which intends to securely compute data based on A and B). A and B are semi-honest.

A proposed secure protocol like this:

1. Alice generates a one-time-use **random matrix $R_A$ from the uniform continues distribution $U(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ is the minimum and maximum values in $M_A$.**, $R_A$ is used as the secret key.
2. Then Alice add $M_A$ to $R_A$ to obtain $MR_A\quad \operatorname{Enc}(M_A) = M_A + R_A$,
3. She sends $MR_A$ to Bob

**My question:**

1. Is this protocol satisfy the one-time-pad encryption or secure?
2. Regarding zero-knowledge, in the proposed protocol a, b defined as the minimum and maximum values of $M_A$, then the attacker will know the minimum and maximum values of $M_A$, is that violate zero-knowledge? How should I define the value of a and b in U(a, b) to generate $R_A$
3. Actually, is the proposed protocol more like a random mask $M_A$ by $R_A$? I do not clearly know the difference between them.

---

#### Followings are my understanding of my question.

From the textbook, I know that the one-time-pad encryption is defined in the bitstream( the plaintext, key, ciphertext are transformed in the bit format)
I also know that the secret key should be truly random and used only once.

**Could you please help me to figure it out or discuss it with me?**

Comment: From what set are the entries of MA? Which addition operation is used?

Comment: In the first paragraph, I can't see how "him" could refer to Bob: _send $M_A$ to Bob_ is making all information about $M_A$ known to Bob, isn't it? Also, in cryptography, we use reals with extreme caution: it's simply impossible to transfer an arbitrary real from one point to another over SSL, for most reals requires an infinite amount of information bits to be exactly represented. That use of reals (without quantified precision requirement) makes the question unorthodox, and the goal even less clear.

Comment: Let me clarify. Bob will receive a matrix sent by Alice, this matrix should be an encrypted version of the true matrix(M_A) generated from Alice since the M_A is Alice's private data should be kept secret. For SSL used in the proposed protocol can be neglected. We only consider with the received encrypted version of M_A, bob knows nothing about M_A. @fgrieu Besides, I do not clearly know your meaning of impossible to transfer arbitrary real via SSL. For precision, the protocol is supposed to be no information lost when recovering M_A from the ciphertext given the decrypt key.

Comment: For any bit string of $n$ bits $b_i$, the real $x=\sum (1+b_i)\,4^{-b_i}$ reversibly encode the whole bitstring and its length, thus there is no limit to the number of bits necessary to encode some reals, thus there mathematically exists reals which storage or transmission by computer means is impossible. That's why computers never use reals (only approximations), and crypto does not deal with encryption of reals.

Comment: Homomorphic encryption can be used to encrypt real numbers, the newly proposed Microsoft SEAL have many example to encrpyt matrix no matter integer or float, besides we can change the irrational number to the float.

Comment: What is the point here?  There is no receiver of meaningful information, there is nothing Bob can do with the matrix. Alice could just send randomness (without any real information), and it would not change anything. Why does Alice even have a private matrix? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: The proposed just one of the steps for another protocol( which intends to collaborate A and B data to compute function F, without letting A and B knows both private data), by this stage, I just want to make sure Bob cannot recover M_A, there is no need to know the detail of the another protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the U(a,b) be continuous uniform distribution or discrete over the value space of MA?

Given that the input numbers are actually irrational non-uniformly distributed numbers, a continuous distribution would is necessary. As an example for this assume you have the entries $1,2,\sqrt 5$ in your matrix and if you'd use only these to mask then you could clearly tell which value was *not* encrypted. For example when you see $1+\sqrt 5$ as a ciphertext you know that $2$ could not have been encrypted which violates perfect secrecy.

> Actually, is the proposed protocol more like a random mask $M_A$ by $R_A$?

There is no practical difference between "Masking" and "One-Time-Pad like encryption". The only theoretical difference I see in usage is that the former is usually used when the masked value is somehow processsed further (e.g. in blind signatures).

> Is this protocol satisfy the one-time-pad encryption or secure?

Well, it doesn't specify how $R_A$ reaches B for decryption, but let's assume that it somehow confidentially does. As it stands the scheme does not achieve perfect secrecy. This is because if the largest element in $M_A$ is 10 and you see a ciphertext of 20 you *know* that it was constructed as $10+10$ or even weaker if you see a ciphertext larger than $12$ you know that the encrypted value could not have been smaller than 2 which violates the fact that you cannot learn anything about the underlying plaintext for perfectly secret encryption. This is why you need a wrap-around into the plaintext space (i.e. $10+1$ yielding e.g. 2) and a continuous distribution. Also note that using the actual maximum of the elements of $M_A$ for the above is not enough, you need to use the *theoretically possible maximum* as to not leak that e.g. the theoretical maximum is not actually reached.

*However*, I have an alternative scheme suggestion (which is different from previous versions of this question and saves you from worrying about ranges). You simply take memory representation of your matrix $M_A$ as a list / vector / array of bytes. Then you generate a container of uniformly random distributed bytes of the same length using your favourite cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator. Then you XOR the memory representations bit-by-bit. The second container is effectively your $R_A$ now.

> How about defining $a, b$ as samples from another uniform distribution $U(c,d)$, where $d > c > 0$

This would work if $0 < c \leq a \leq b\leq d$ holds as long as all addition results don't leave the interval $[c;d]$, e.g. using wrap-around so that everything above $d$ gets added on top of $c$ (with appropriate reversal during decryption). The idea here is that it suffices if the space of the randomness is larger than the plaintext space.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please give me some detailed explanation for the difference between "Masking" and "One-Time-Pad like encryption"?  What is the definition of the range and wrap around at the edges in the sentence: if you generate your floats randomly continuously in the range and wrap around at the edges? (Do you mean the range of the M_A? Actually, I just wonder should I define the a and b of U(a,b) within the minimum and maximum values in _A, How about defining a, b as samples from another uniform distribution U(c,d), where d > c > 0.

Comment: And for your proposed alternative scheme suggestion, the combination of 15 integers should be 15! combination, not very clear defining a lookup-table for each of the 15 combinations, and what the relationship between encoding them as 4-bit unsigned integers (i.e. packing two into one byte) and generate a uniformly random bit sequence for the encoded matrix?

Comment: @Amor I tried to clarify my answer, is there still something unclear?

Comment: 1.for example, e.g. 2+4.3=2.3 to stay in the interval [1;5], it seems that all cipher numbers stay in the same range as the plaintext, with the ciphertext, the attacker will know the range of the plaintext. I just wonder whether it is zero-knowledge.

Comment: 2. Why we should always keep the addition result MR_A falls into the plaintext range(M_A), so could you please explain, the difference between M_A + R_Aand (M_A + R_A - a) % (a - b) ( % denotes mod operation), given  M_A is in [a, b](actually the range of the former just falls into [2a, 2b]), besides, could you explain that the reason why This would work if 0<≤≤≤ holds as long as all addition results don't leave the interval [;].

Comment: 3. For your proposed scheme, 15 pairs, I do not know how you encode the 15 integers, since if the Euclidean distance between two of the row vectors is very large(note that it is the one element of the M_A,  how can we encode is by 4 bits?) Or we just simple transfer every element of M_A into bit format to obtain the length of the bit-format of M_A. In practice, how we generate a uniformly random bitsequence?

Comment: @Amor It appears I miss-understood the comment under your question. If you compute the euclidean distance between arbitrary-length vectors of the integers 1-5 you can indeed get essentially any algebraic number as a result (and thus entry for $M_A$).

Comment: @Amor I have tried to clarify the answer again.

Comment: Thanks for your so detailed clarification! Regarding zero knowledge, we make the ciphertext to stay in the value space of the plaintext, then the attacker will at least know that the value range(it might be the minimum and maximum value of the plaintext) In that case it still satisfy the perfect secrete?

Comment: In addition to your proposed scheme, how about generating R_A from a continuous uniform distribution in (0,1), and multiply RA with MA. In that way, the ciphertext just stay in the value space of the  plaintext.

Comment: @Amor You are indeed correct, one needs to use the theoretical maximum (and minimum) and not the actual maximum of $M_A$ for the noise bound. As for multiplication this will not work as when you see a ciphertext of value $3$ you _know_ that it couldn't have been the result of encrypting a $2$.

Comment: so how should I choose the theoretical maximum of $M_A$? And if I want to multiply  $R_A$ with $M_A$, is there any secure protocol by defining $R_A$ from U(a,b)?

Comment: @Amor You said that the entries of $M_A$ are the euclidean distances between vectors of elements of 1-5, in that case if your longest pair of vectors has $n$ entries each the maximum should be $\sqrt{n(5-1)^2}=4\sqrt n$. As for real-valued multiplication I don't see any way to make it work (right now).

Comment: Thanks!  For your answered security holds if 0<c<=a <=b <= d,  what if c > a, or d < b, actually attacker do not know a and b, from my limited understanding, when c>a but d> b or c>a, d< b just change the value space of M_A, is there any other security considerations?

Comment: @Amor The important thing is that the noise has a greater range than the plaintext which includes the plaintext. Else there will be ciphertexts which could not have been produced by certain plaintexts.

Comment: btw, if the matrix M_A is defined in Z( integer field), will (M_A + R_A)   without mod operation could be adopt? Suppose there are M_A and M_B and R_A defined in the field F, what if I compute M_A  + R_A to send to C and then M_B - R_A to C, could M_A and M_B kept secrete by this operation?

Comment: @Amor If you don't apply a mod operation and use unbounded integers then an adversary can exclude some values based on the maximum value of the key-value (e.g. they can exclude small values if they see really large ciphertexts). For the three-party operation note that an adversary can compute (M_A+R_A)+(M_B-R_A) to get (M_A+M_B) which leaks information about the two matrices unless one is uniformly random.

Comment: the key value you mean values in R_A? But R_A should be kept secrete how the attacker knows its maximum value? And besides, how about the attacker do not know encyption method, in this example they only see the results of M_A + R_A. Since in this protocol, there is no need to recover M_A and it intends to make third-party to compute M_A + M_B.

Comment: In addition, with the mod operation, the cipher will still give the maximum and minimum values to the attacker, it is possible that gives attacker to exclude some plaintext. I cannot see the clear difference between the above and " an adversary can exclude some values based on the maximum value of the key-value (e.g. they can exclude small values if they see really large ciphertexts)."

Comment: @Amor It is generally assumed that an adversary knows everything about a system except the keys. This includes how the keys are used and from what sets the keys are drawn. The thing about modular reduction in this context is that the sum of two large values can get small again as opposed to normal addition's properties. As for M_A and M_B it sounded like M_B-R_A and M_A+R_A were both transmitted and you both encrypted them so you apparently don't want to leak information about M_A nor M_B which is exactly what happens if you re-use R_A in this way...

Comment: I agree that generally assumed that an adversary knows everything about a system except the keys.  However, A and B are the semi-honest server, according to the definition of the semi-honest server, they only have its input and must obey the protocol with no auxiliary information, it should mean that they will not get know other things such as range of the key or the data encryption method? Or I misundering semi-honest definition？

Comment: @Amor Semi-honest means that an adversary is bound by the protocol for the messages it sends. It can do whatever with the data it sees or receives and tries to get an advantage through that.

Comment: Totally understood with thanks！Btw, if you have free time, could you please have a look at this question? It is about random masking a matrix after homomorphic encryption, my course design. Actually I have try all my best to search for security proof regarding this kind of multiplicative random but no reliable results found.https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40783/security-of-homomorphic-encryption-schemes?rq=1